# VS2010 : How to run devenv to not parallelize the build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, devenv

I use devenv.exe to pass it a sln file and use /Rebuild switch, internally the devenv.exe spins up multiple msbuild's. I have a need to run unparalleled build, with only one thread of msbuild. Surely, I can use directly msbuild.exe with /M set to 1, but I have a specific requirement to use devenv.exe.

Is there any way by a command line switch or by using some environment variable which will allow me to do aforementioned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So you want it to compile slower?

In your project file under **C/C++ General** you'll see a **Multi-processor Compilation**. Set that to **No**. Else remove the **/MP** switch from the commandline to cl.exe depending how you are compiling.

Comment: "Is there any way by a command line switch or by using some environment variable"

Comment: I mentioned the commandline switch but he's using devenv.exe so he has the IDE and is building from solution files so the easiest way is to save the projects appropriately.

Comment: I figured he was talking about passing /m:1 to msbuild.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above solution and it did not work. Here's the correct solution I found from this duplicate topic:

[How to do a parallel build in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172205/how-to-do-a-parallel-build-in-visual-studio-2010)

```
1. Tools -> Options
2. Projects and Solutions\VC++ Project Settings
3. Maximum concurrent C++ compilations
4. Set it to 1 (or the desired number)
```